# How can i get unique options in MUI Autocomplete?

Tags: select, material-ui, autocomplete

I am using Autocomplete, but I have a requirement where if a value from the dropdown menu has been selected, the next Autocomplete should not show the same value again.

The current situation is that once I select a value, it gets removed from the dropdown menu. As a result, if I make a wrong selection, I am unable to go back and modify it.

```js
{
                formData.createClass.map((item, index)=>(
                  <div key={index} style={{width: '70%'}}>
                    <Autocomplete
                      multiple
                      label="學生*"
                      id="createStudent"
                      options={
                        studentOptions(index).length > 0
                        ? [
                          {
                            value: SELECT_ALL, name: '全班',
                          },
                          ...studentOptions(index)
                        ] : []
                      }
                      disableCloseOnSelect
                      variant='outlined'
                      getOptionLabel={(option) => 
                        option.value === SELECT_ALL
                        ? '全班'
                        : option.name
                      }
                      renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
                        <li {...props}>
                          <Checkbox
                            icon={icon}
                            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                            checked={selected}
                          />
                          {option.name}
                        </li>
                      )}
                      limitTags={1}
                      renderInput={(params) => {
                        return (
                          <TextField {...params} label="學生*" />
                        );
                      }}
                      value={formData.createClass[index].studentList}
                      key={studentOptions(index)}
                      onChange={handleStudentChange(index, studentOptions(index))}
                      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>option.name === value.value || ''
                    }
                    />
                ))
              }
```

#### onChange

```js
  const handleStudentChange = (index, allList) => (_, value) =>{
    if(value.some((v)=> v.value === SELECT_ALL)){
      setFormData(prevFormData => {
        const updatedCreateClass = [...prevFormData.createClass];
        updatedCreateClass[index] = {
          ...updatedCreateClass[index],
          studentList: allList
        };
        return {
          ...prevFormData,
          createClass: updatedCreateClass
        };
      });
    }else{
      setFormData(prevFormData => {
        const updatedCreateClass = [...prevFormData.createClass];
        updatedCreateClass[index] = {
          ...updatedCreateClass[index],
          studentList: value
        };
        return {
          ...prevFormData,
          createClass: updatedCreateClass
        };
      });
    }
  };
```

#### options

```js
  const studentOptions = useCallback((index) =>{
    const currentClassUsers = currentOrganization.find((item)=>item.id === formData.createClass[index]?.value)?.users;
    const cleanCurrentClass = _.filter(currentClassUsers, (value) => {
      const isValueUnique = !_.some(selectedOptions, { value }) && !_.some(formData.createClass, (classItem) =>
        _.some(classItem.studentList, { value })
      );
    
      return isValueUnique;
    });

    const optionsList = cleanCurrentClass.map((item)=>({
      value: item,
      name: item
    }));

    return optionsList;

  }, [currentClass]);
```

#### currentClassUsers

```js
['panda34', 'panda31', 'panda30', 'panda29', 'panda28', 'panda27', 'panda22', 'panda21']
```

#### selectedOptions

```js
[{name: '0928360517', value: '0928360517'}]
```

#### formData.createClass

```js
[name: 'name', value: "df98ad2b09114cbe82a658c47edf0eb4", studentList: []]
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the Autocomplete **filterSelectedOptions** property to *false*?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but the problem persists because my options are subject to change with each state transition.

Comment: Could you please somehow re-state your question? The question does not seem related to the description that follows. It isn't clear what the problem is. It sounds like you are saying you have a requirement to remove a selected option; then the problem is that the option is removed. But, if that is the requirement, then what is the problem?

Comment: I hope to have my current options fixed.(
The content of the current dropdown menu must be the portion that has not been selected in any other dropdown menus. ) 
Just like if B selects 1, then A = [1,2,3], it should display [2,3].
If I trigger an onchange event now, it will cause my options to be recalculated. As a result, when I click the dropdown menu again, the previously selected item will no longer be available in the dropdown menu.

Comment: Thanks. This description is clear. But, the problem has not yet been declared. Is the problem that the selected option from **menu B** still appears in **menu A**?

Comment: In fact, currently menu A has been filtered correctly. However, when I select a value in menu A, it triggers the onChange event, which in turn triggers setFormData and modifies my formData. As a result, each time I obtain the options, they become shorter.

Comment: You say *each time I obtain the options, they become shorter*. But, this is what your requirement says should happen. Your requirement is to **remove** the selected option. If you remove the selection option, the list should become shorter. I still haven't heard the problem. This sounds like a good case for you to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please try to post **all** the code necessary for someone to compile and run a minimal example (a smaller version than your existing code) that demonstrates the problem. Thanks.